# My Animation in SwiftUI is not working properly

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-animation

I have a problem with animation in SwiftUI, if I'm using `.animation`, my animation is not working.

```
ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
    VStack {
        Button("Button") {
            showView.toggle()
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    
    if showView {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
            .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.5)
            .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
            .animation(.easeInOut, value: showView)
    }
}
.ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
```

But if I'm using `withAnimation` in my button's action closure, and delete `.animation` or keep it, it is working.

```
ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
    VStack {
        Button("Button") {
            withAnimation {
                showView.toggle()
            }
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    
    if showView {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
            .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.5)
            .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
            .animation(.easeInOut, value: showView)
    }
}
.ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
```

Can someone explain me how this works ? I'm trying with `DispatchQueue.main.async`, it's still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining 2 different states:

1. With `RoundedRectangle` if showView = true
2. Without `RoundedRectangle` if showView = false

So, every time `showView` changes, the `body` will be re-rendered. If it toggles from false -> true, then `RoundedRectangle` will be displayed instantly without any animations because it's not here until `showView = true`. And if it toggles from true -> false, then it can be dismissed with animation because now, it's a part of the View. You may try this to make it show/disappear more smoothly:

```swift
ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
    VStack {
        Button("Button") {
            showView.toggle()
        }

        Spacer()
    }

    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
        .frame(height: showView ? (UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.5) : 0)
        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: showView)
}
.ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
```

Comment: so i need value for else right ?

Comment: It depends on you, however, a single instance of view with a different layout gives better performance. Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/) from 11:00.

Comment: its only work using ternary ? if using normal if { }else {} not working. why ?

Comment: like this : 

if showView { .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.5) } else { .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.0) }

Comment: You should check the video first. How can you make an if statement with a single property like `.frame`?

Comment: oh its because the view identity, can disrupt the animation because SwiftUI sees them as distinct entities rather than a single view changing its state right ? i just want make a clear so i can understand.

Comment: wooohh Thank you son !! im appreciate your answer. 

Answer (score 1):

Put `.animation(..)` on the outer containing view like this:

```
ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
    Button("Button") {
        showView.toggle()
    }
        
    if showView {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
            ...
    }
}
.ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
.animation(.easeInOut, value: showView) // <-- on ZStack, not on Rectangle
```

The reason this fixes the issue is that now SwiftUI *always* knows, that changes of `showView` need animations.

In your code, the Rectangle is completely removed from the view hierarchy when `showView` is false. Meaning: it does not exist for SwiftUI and thus it also doesn't know that there is an animation.

Once the flag changes to `true`, SwiftUI will just do a normal rerender, will see a change in the `if` statement and will now render the Rectangle. And *then*, the animation is set. *After* the view was defined. So SwiftUI will know that *now* changes of `showView` need to be animated. But by that time it's too late to animate the showing.

Moving the `.animation` out of the `if` means, that the animation is defined in a place that always exists, no matter what state the view is in. So when the flag changes, SwiftUI rerenders and knows that any differences in the UI caused by this change, need to be animated.

Son's answer works for the same reason, but uses a very different approach. In his answer, SwiftUI *always* shows the Rectangle. Meaning SwiftUI always knows about it and about the animation that is defined on it. In his answer he just reduces the height of the view to 0 if it should be hidden. So the view is still there, it's just that the user can't see it. Once the flag changes, the view doesn't technically get shown, it just animates it's change in height. Doing that might just cause other UI glitches, depending on what you show in the view that gets shown/hidden. It might happen that during the animation the content gets "shoved around", squashed/stretched etc.

Comment: your answer also correct. but i want more the answer why i cant use like that. appreciate your answer. 

Comment: @Suweey I added an explanation to my answer and also compared it to Sons answer, what the differences are and what issues might arise with his solution.

Comment: wow thanks for your answer. its more clear answer for my question. so its depend what i want for that. hidden or just change the height. right ?

Comment: Yes exactly. :)

Comment: For a detailed explanation of why conditional statements break animation and how to avoid them, see [link](https://www.drowsydays.com/Drowsy-Days-blog/Entries/2023/12/the-swift-ternary-conditional-operator-from-obscure-to-essential-with-swiftui-1.html)